# Can a Java ZipEntry be extracted in C/C++

Tags: java, c++, zip

The client is implemented in C++ and server is in Java. The zipEntry from java can't be extracted by zlib/miniz's API inflate at client. Is there a solution in C/C++?

Server Code, which was carved in stone. And as they say: customer is god.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteoutstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(byteoutstream);
java.util.zip.ZipEntry ze = new java.util.zip.ZipEntry("data");
zos.putNextEntry(ze);
zos.write(B64Code_test.encode(str).getBytes("GBK"));
zos.close();
byteoutstream.close();
return byteoutstream.toByteArray();
...
send bytes via socket..
```

Comment: Java is probably a JAR file, which is a little different than a ZIP file (but not much). Or, ZIP is a little different than Java JAR files (but not much). See [Binary Difference in Zip/Jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/753576/608639). So yes, its possible. But I'm not sure what library you should use.

Comment: Is the trouble because you are encoding your data?

Comment: Try `libzip`: http://linux.die.net/man/3/libzip

Comment: @Scary-Wombat Yes, but this is a protocol between c/s. The compression is a step can't be omitted.

Comment: It can be extracted in C++ with a zip library. zlib is not a zip library.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But, you can't mix the [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) compression you are currently using in Java with the GZip compression used in your C++. Instead, use a [`GZipOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) in Java (or you'll need to find a LZW library for C++).

Something like,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteoutstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZipOutputStream zos = new GZipOutputStream(byteoutstream);
zos.write(B64Code_test.encode(str).getBytes("GBK"));
zos.close();
return byteoutstream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: The server was carved in stone

Comment: Then you need to go find a LZW library that can handle zip files. I found [unpdf](https://code.google.com/p/unpdf/) (it includes lzwcoder) with just a little google-fu.

Answer (score 1):

Enlightened by:
http://choruscode.blogspot.sg/2012/05/uncompressing-pkzip-files-with-zlib-and.html
and
example2.c of https://code.google.com/p/miniz/

I try to save the Data into a file, and then process the archive file using miniz zip API.

And finally, the mem (not zip file) API is found in miniz.c.

```
#include "miniz.c"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  mz_zip_archive zipar;
  int status;
  void *p;
  size_t unsize;

  /* ============================== uncompress */
  int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  char buf[2048];
  int n = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
  buf[n] = 0;

  memset(&zipar, 0, sizeof(zipar));
  /* file OK */
  /* status = mz_zip_reader_init_file(&zipar, argv[1], 0); */
  /* if (!status) { */
  /*   printf("%s %d: fails\n", __FILE__, __LINE__); */
  /*   exit(1); */
  /* } */

  /* mem OK */
  status = mz_zip_reader_init_mem(&zipar, buf, n, 0);
  p = mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_heap(&zipar, "data", &unsize, 0);
  if (!p) {
    printf("%s %d: fails\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    exit(1);
  } else {
    printf("datasize %d, data: \n%s\n", unsize, p);
  }
  mz_zip_reader_end(&zipar);


  /* ============================== compress */
  /* file OK */
  memset(&zipar, 0, sizeof(zipar));
  /* mz_zip_writer_init_file(&zipar, "xmsgfs", 0); */
  /* mz_zip_writer_add_mem(&zipar, "data", p, unsize, 0); */
  /* mz_zip_writer_finalize_archive(&zipar); */
  /* mz_zip_writer_end(&zipar); */

  /* mem OK */
  mz_zip_writer_init_heap(&zipar, 0, 0);
  mz_zip_writer_add_mem(&zipar, "data", p, unsize, 0);
  void *c;
  int csize;
  mz_zip_writer_finalize_heap_archive(&zipar, &c, &csize);
  mz_zip_writer_end(&zipar);

  mz_free(p);  /* !!! */


  /* re uncompress, mem method */
  memset(&zipar, 0, sizeof(zipar));
  status = mz_zip_reader_init_mem(&zipar, c, csize, 0);
  p = 0; unsize = 0;
  p = mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_heap(&zipar, "data", &unsize, 0);
  if (!p) {
    printf("%s %d: fails\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    exit(1);
  } else {
    printf("datasize %d, data: \n%s\n", unsize, p);
  }
  mz_zip_reader_end(&zipar);

  mz_free(c);

  return 0;
}
```